# Kernel mismatch on CentOS 7.5 causing installation problems

Tags: installation, kernel, centos-7

I am trying to install Sysdig Falco on a CentOS 7.5 system. The kernel is -

```
[root@localhost ~]# uname -r
3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64
```

Now Falco requires Kernel Dev packages to be installed to build its kernel modules. Kernel modules for the above kernel version are no longer available and if the new packages are installed, they are for kernel version 3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls /usr/src/kernels/
3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64
```

Falco gets installed but the falco-probe kernel object does not get compiled, which makes Falco unable to run. I can't tinker with the installed kernel as that's the base image for production machines. Any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Welcome, did you have `dkms` package installed?

Comment: Yes, `dkms --version= dkms:2.6`